# Model Error Account object has no attribute 'transactions'

Tags: django, django-models

It's my understanding this should work...

```
   def _balance(self):
        aggregates = self.transactions.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))
        sum = aggregates['sum']
        return D('0') if sum is None else sum
```

But I get the following error: **'Account' object has no attribute 'transactions'**

I have the related name transactions set on the the model transaction. See my models below

```
class Account(models.Model):
    OPEN, FROZEN, CLOSED = 'Open', 'Frozen', 'Closed'
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=OPEN)
    # For performance, we keep a cached balance
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=10,
                                  default=D('0'), null=True)
    #FK
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def _balance(self):
            aggregates = self.transactions.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))
            sum = aggregates['sum']
            return D('0') if sum is None else sum


class Transaction(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account',
                                related_name='transactions')
```

Any idea's why my model function does not work?

Thank You.

Comment: What if you put the `Transaction` class above the `Account` class? It may need to know about the reverse relation first maybe? Or maybe you could try running `syncdb` I don't know, but I agree it looks like it should work...

Comment: Hi @Ngenator, ok I found the problem but no idea why it was the issue. When I remove the 'meta' class  unique_together = ('transfer', 'account') and  abstract = True it works.

Comment: Hmm, having that info could have helped someone spot the problem. In the future, don't leave out info like that from the code you post, even if you don't think it's important!